# Obtain Source<B> (Sink<B>) out of Source<A> (Sink<A>) and f:A->B (f:B->A)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

In order to build sources & sinks on top of existing ones (as opposed to do it from scratch or with more boilerplate), I'd like to:

- Append a conversion function `f:A->B` to a `Source<A>` in order to get a `Source<B>` (corresponds to *map* in FP circles)
- Prepend a conversion function `f:B->A` to a `Sink<A>` in order to get a `Sink<B>` (corresponds to *contramap* in FP circles)

In Scala, this pattern is commonly used by JSON libraries such as Circe:

- https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html#custom-encodersdecoders

Does this pattern apply well to the case at hand (Flink sources & sinks)?

Otherwise what would be the recommended way of approaching this problem?

As a special instance of the problem, you might consider the following example:

- You have an existing DataStream connector (source & sink) which works for a fixed data type
- You want to reuse that connector for the Table/SQL API, which requires `RowData` as the data type

The official docs already touch upon this here:

- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/#project-configuration

In particular:

> If you want to develop a connector that needs to bridge with
> DataStream APIs (i.e. if you want to adapt a DataStream connector to
> the Table API), you need to add this dependency:
> "org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java-bridge:1.16-SNAPSHOT"

Here you can see this in action within the kafka connector:

- [KafkaDynamicSource.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0394a01ebb4f1c6b3c3534acc58dd2467c8196e1/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/KafkaDynamicSource.java#L226)
- [KafkaDynamicSink.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/025675725336cd572aa2601be525efd4995e5b84/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/KafkaDynamicSink.java#L218)

Finally, see also the original question posted in the User mailing list:

- https://lists.apache.org/thread/rb1s5rt7qtjb53nm4psnbgblzhcc7t7r

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't really have to work that hard. If, for example, you have a `DataStream<Customer> customerStream` where `Customer` is a Flink POJO, it's enough to do

```
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("Customers", customerStream);
```

and then you have a Customers Table you can use like any other Table.

You can use `toDataStream` and `toChangelogStream` to convert tables to datastreams before sinking them with datastream sinks. If you need to, you can always chain a `MapFunction` in between to do additional conversion. For example, I once found myself doing this when I had to have the output in a very particular format:

```java
Table hourlyMax = tableEnv.sqlQuery(...);

DataStream<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> resultsAsStreamOfTuples =
    tableEnv.toDataStream(hourlyMax)
        .map(row -> new Tuple3<>(
            row.<LocalDateTime>getFieldAs("window_end")
               .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
               .toInstant()
               .toEpochMilli(),
            row.<Long>getFieldAs("driverId"),
            row.<Float>getFieldAs("sumOfTips")))
        .returns(Types.TUPLE(Types.LONG, Types.LONG, Types.FLOAT));

resultsAsStreamOfTuples.addSink(sink);
```

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/ describes this in more detail and includes examples.

Of course, all of the above only applies to the special case of converting between streams and tables. But for the more general case, I would generally recommend using a chained `MapFunction` instead of creating a custom connector that wraps an existing connector.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I'll definitely take your advice as the preferred way to go.